# Someone can explain for me this Laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some code like below, the thing I want to ask is with the exactly same `// dd($example->count()) #10` why put `dd()` on each different line has different value ? What change my `$example` event I never reassign it ?

```
$example = $car->wheels()->whereBetween(
        'created_at',
        [
            $starDay->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
            $today->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')
        ]
    )

$total =  $example->count();

// dd($example->count()) #10

$totalSuccess = $example->where('status', 'good')->count();

// dd($example->count()) # 5

$colors = $example->select('color', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('color')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

// dd($example->count()) # []
```

Comment: I guess `count()` is an object method. And each time we call `count()` that change `$example` object `count` property. That a reason why we call same `dd($example->count())`  but return different value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value changes because each time you are adding more and more different clauses (like `where`) to your query. Those calls actually change the query object itself and the changes persist.

1. At first you have query object in `$example` with only `whereBetween` clause. It returns you count of 10 rows in your database.
2. Then you add `where('status', 'good')` to the query and it narrows down the selection even more down to 5 rows.
3. Lastly you change your `$example` query with `select(...)` and `groupBy()` calls.

In Laravel query builder objects are *mutated* when you add query constructions to it. So when you call `$example->where(...)` your `$example` query builder object will now have that `where` clause.